# Can UILongPressGestureRecognizer be used together with touch events like touchesMoved?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

If I add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to an object is there a way to get a `touchesMoved` event in that object to fire after my longGesture selector responds to the longpress gesture without having to lift your finger first?

What I am seeing is that once the selector recognizes the long gesture the `touchesMoved` events will not respond until you remove your finger from the object. In other words you cannot Press, pause, move.

Is this even possible with a gesture recognizer or is the only way to do this is with a tap and hold approach.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of relying on the `touchesMoved` method, you can add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` along with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your view.

Comment: Ya you should go with Simon.Well you can even use the touch events with getures,but if you have all the gesture methods available to use which are pretty much to use then touch methods.Then why to go with them just use the gestures.

Comment: Thanks. That pointed me in the right direction. I am getting the behavior I am looking for now.

Answer (score 4):

```
    longPressGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

Comment: This solves the problem when you have longPress in one view but touchesBegan etc in a subview.