# pressGestureRecognizer and touchesBegan

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa, touchesbegan

I have the following problem.
I am using a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to put a UIView into a "toggle mode". If the `UIView` is in "toggle mode" the user is able to drag the UIView around the screen. For dragging the UIView around the screen I am using the methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded`.

It works, but: I have to lift my finger in order to drag it, because the `touchesBegan` method got already called and therefore is not called again and therefore I can't drag the `UIView` around the screen.

Is there any way to manually call `touchesBegan` after `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` got triggered (`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` changes a BOOL value and the `touchesBegan` only works if this BOOL is set to YES).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can UILongPressGestureRecognizer be used together with touch events like touchesMoved?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313648/can-uilongpressgesturerecognizer-be-used-together-with-touch-events-like-touches)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a continuous gesture recognizer, so rather than resorting to `touchesMoved` or `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, just check for `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged`, e.g.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (void)handleGesture:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint location = [gesture locationInView:gesture.view];

    if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {
        // user held down their finger on the screen

        // gesture started, entering the "toggle mode"
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {
        // user did not lift finger, but now proceeded to move finger

        // do here whatever you wanted to do in the touchesMoved
    }
    else if (gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        // user lifted their finger

        // all done, leaving the "toggle mode"
    }
}
```

Comment: I've looked for this answer for many a night my good sir. I've tried just about everything I knew how in order to get touchesMoved to fire while in the middle of a long press... it simply won't work. Checking the state .Changed did the trick. Thanks a ton, @Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use UIPanGestureRecognizer as it a recommended gesture for dragging.

1. You can configure the min. and max. number of touches required for a panning, using the following the properties:

   **maximumNumberOfTouches**

   **minimumNumberOfTouches**
2. You can handle the states like Began, Changed and Ended, like having animation for the required states.
3. Using the below method translate the point to the UIView in which you want it.

   `- (void)setTranslation:(CGPoint)translation inView:(UIView *)view`

   example:

   1. You have to use a global variable to retain the old frame. Get this in UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan.
   2. When the state is UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged. You can use the

   > ```
   > -(void) pannningMyView:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*) panGesture{
   >
   >    if(panGesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
   >      //retain the original state
   >    }else if(panGesture.state==UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged){
   >    CGPoint translatedPoint=[panGesture translationInView:self.view];
   >   //here you manage to get your new drag points.
   >   }
   >  }
   > ```
4. Velocity of the drag. Based on the velocity you can provide a animation to show bouncing of a UIView

   `- (CGPoint)velocityInView:(UIView *)view`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how to I get the coordinates for the translation?